# form submit in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new in cakephp and I want to insert form data in database but value not inserting. Where I am wrong ?
This is my view (first I want to add only one field). Thanks in advance

in view -

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');

echo $this->Form->input('title');

echo $this->Form->end('Add');
```

in controller =

```
public function index()

{

$this->layout=false;

if($this->is->request('post'):

$this->request->data["Post"]["title"]=$this->request->data["Post"]["title"]

$this->Post->save($this->request->data);

endif;

}
```

Comment: `if($this->is->request('post'):` this should be `if($this->request->is('post'):`

Comment: Sir, i did but Still not working

Comment: Did you see any error ?

Comment: no i not getting any error, i using cakephp first time

Comment: With that many syntax errors, I'd doubt that you'd see anything other than error messages.

Comment: any solution for this ? or can you tell me how can i save any field value into database

Comment: You missed semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your controller code.

Try this:

```
 public function index() {

     $this->layout=false;

     if($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {

            echo "Save successful!";

        } else {

            echo "Save failed!";
        }

        exit;

     }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here i can give you an example to INSERT any record in cakephp with multiple fields

just take look in function and you may have good idea

```
        $data = $this->request->data;
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $ret_save = $this->Post->save();
            if ($ret_save) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Save successful!'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'index'));
            }else{
               echo "Save failed!";
           }
```

hope this code will help you.